# Is it a good idea to use pointer to a pointer to a vector for constructing a matrix

Tags: c++

I saw the C++ code extensively in my new company that uses the pointer to a pointer to a vector to store data and I don't find it very intuitive. Is it a common practice to use this syntax?

```
vector <T>** data;
data = new vector<T>*(colSize);
for (int i=0 ; i < colSize; ++i)
{
   data[i] = new vector<T>(); 
}
```

Comment: Nope, it sure isn't.  Why dynamically allocate a vector and prevent it from managing memory for you?  Don't confuse the (small) amount of memory needed for the vector with the (larger) memory that it allocates to store its data.  Also, locality of data is crap here.  Just allocate one big vector and index yourself (row * y + column, though this assumes that the matrix is rectangular).

Comment: I guess if the columns of the matrix don't all have the same number of elements and if rows and/or columns needs to be extendable, it might be ok. For 3D, absolutely not.

Comment: That is, (row * columns + column)

Comment: The argument I am given is that the person is using pointers because object of type <T> can be of large size and he would avoid this problem using this syntax, but I don't seem to get it.

Comment: @vkaul11: You don't get it because he is wrong.

Comment: What if we don't have fixed size of the matrix and we don't know it before hand?

Answer (score 0):

No, you simply use a `vector` to a `vector` (or `std::array` if size is fixed):

```
vector<vector<T>> data;
```

Comment: `std::array`/`boost::array` should be used if the size is fixed

Comment: Unless you want to be able to efficiently swap rows, which sometimes arises. Then you want `vector` as the inner type even if the size is fixed (or a `unique_ptr` to an `array`, but it becomes an annoying amount of typing just to fix the size) . Likewise with the outer type if you want to efficiently swap or move the whole matrix.

Comment: Steve, the argument I was given was  that the person is using pointers because object of type <T> can be of large size and he would avoid this problem using this syntax, but I don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

A more normal approach would be along these lines:

```
    int colSize = 10;
    int rowSize = 12;
    typedef int T;

    std::vector<std::vector<T> > data(colSize);
    std::for_each ( data.begin(), data.end(), 
        [rowSize] (std::vector<T>& row)
    {
        row.resize(rowSize);
    });
```

However, as commented usually by "matrix" we do always mean a fixed row size (as in the example), and use a single 1D underlying array or `vector` and provide an interface to provide a `2D` ( or `3D` or whatever) look up.